# Javascript code works from console but not file

Tags: javascript, html

I was recently introduced to Web Storage on my current course and have been tasked with taking input from a text field (input) using a button, then creating a key and value for this text field data. It seemed rather trivial. I produced some code in attempt to get it working. However the code did not work as expected.

Here is the (non-working) code I managed to produce:

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <p>Forename:</p>
    <input type="text" id="FName"><br>
    <button type="button" id="Submit">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
var SubmitButton = document.getElementById('Submit');
var TextField = document.getElementById('FName');

SubmitButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    ToTextField();
});

function ToTextField(){
    var input = document.getElementById("FName").value;
    localStorage.setItem("Text", input);
}
```

Though this code does not work, I have analyzed the developer tools tab in my browser (Firefox), and noticed that I get the following error:

```
TypeError: SubmitButton is null [Learn More]    app.js:6:1
```

If I then enter the following lines of JS into the Console (which are the same in my file), the submit button seems to work as I expected it. I can't figure out the problem:

```
var SubmitButton = document.getElementById('Submit');
SubmitButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    ToTextField();
});
```

Can anyone spot the problem I am having here?
Thanks :)

Comment: Try moving the script tag to just before the closing body tag.

Comment: Move `<script>` definition from head to the end of the body, or wait for [DOM is loaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)

Comment: Ah yes, I understand that these elements would not exist at the time of script execution due to the script being loaded first. Thanks a lot and sorry for the duplicate.